# Typescript interface with keys of Generic

Tags: typescript

I am defining a api for a typescript frontend/backend application.

Now I want to write an interface that is allowed to contain all available keys defined in an other interface, prefixed with `filter.`

Lets say I have a user interface

```
interface User {
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
}
```

A User request can be filtered, so my general Request ist extended with FilteredRequest

```
interface FilteredRequest<T> {
  [key: 'filter.' + keyof T]: any;
}
```

Is this possible with typescript?

---

Ok because this is not possible right now.

Also not prefixing the key with someting does not work

```
interface FilteredRequest<T> {
  [key: keyof T]: any;
}
```

`An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'.ts(1023)`

But keyof is designed to return a `string` or `number`

Comment: You can do it with mapped types `type FilteredRequest<T> =  {
  [key in keyof T]: any;
}` or using `Record`: `type FilteredRequest<T> = Record<keyof T, any>`

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not possible in the current (3.4.5) version of Typescript.

[This feature is being debated on github issue.](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754)

Answer (score 1):

Since version 4.1.0, this is now possible by combining template literal types and mapped type 'as' clauses. [See the PR for more info](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336).

```
interface User {
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
}

type FilteredRequest<T> = {
  // `& string` excludes `number` and `symbol` properties
  [K in keyof T & string as `filter.${K}`]: T[K];
}

type FilteredUserRequest = FilteredRequest<User>
//    => type FilteredUserRequest = { "filter.firstname": string; "filter.lastname": string; }
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChnIzBTpghwC2EAXMqVKAOYDc+yANnKeVbfU6wC+uXGACeABxQAxYO0hQIAEwBKEAI4BXCKQA8AFQB8yALw42AegvIABgDI6YBiEY3kEAB4J2mpTtsgmhQARtBucCBKtuhiIQD27G4SUHFSUGDAOmwA2gDSyKDIANYQYnEwyPrIDvwuyFy2RPLQAHQAJNi5gjYAurT6eT1CIuJSyLLNikoY0GpaOmCm43IKynPaejNQhrhWBAQAegD8uEA)